# JQuery: JQuery timepicker not working in Safari. Works well in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, timepicker

JQuery Timepicker (timepicker.co) does not work in Safari.

Works well in chrome on MAC.
JQuery version : 1.11.3